# ADD vs. ADD COLUMN in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax

I am trying to add a new column to a pre-existing table on a database upgrade method. I've seen two ways:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

What's the difference?

Comment: The `COLUMN` keyword is optional. No difference at all.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Would be interested to see how you know for sure; I see the flowchart on https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html, is this where?

Comment: I know this because both versions does the exact same thing. Try it yourself and see.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I did test them both (which is why I made the question) but didn't know if there was some extra thing done to the schema somewhere that I was missing. But, good to know! Thanks again

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker Although the page you linked doesn't explicitly say that `COLUMN` is optional, if it _did_ affect the behaviour, that fact (almost certainly) would be mentioned.

Comment: Look again at that page - the "railroad diagram" *does* show that `COLUMN` is optional.

Answer (score 5):

The `COLUMN` keyword is optional. No difference at all.

Try the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Col1 INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Test (Col1) VALUES (1);

ALTER TABLE Test 
ADD Col2 INTEGER NULL;

ALTER TABLE Test 
ADD COLUMN Col3 INTEGER NULL;

SELECT * 
FROM Test
```

The result will be:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1
```

Comment: Considering issues such as performance (e.g. of millions of SQL statements), or how widespread support is (across dozens of database systems, including different versions of the same database), etc...is there *really* no difference? It would be most surprising if that was true.

Comment: @AlainD I'm all for nitpicking, but you've taken it to a whole new level.... First, I find it hard to imagine a scenario where you would hate to consider performance issues of an `alter table` statement. This is usually not a run-time operation and if you're using it in a loop (e.g of millions of SQL statements) - you're probably doing it wrong. Second, about the widespread support across dozens of database systems including different versions - The question is referring to a specific database so it's irrelevant. (though version is not mentioned, I'll grant you that.)

Comment: Errata: You mean "have", not "hate". My comment is not meant as criticism, but does have two serious points: (a) if you're nitpicky enough there is a difference, and (b) "widespread" database versions and systems *is* relevant, despite the OP only mentioning `SQLite` generically - people arrive at this question from many sources and web searches. The question has general relevance to SQL-92 conformance (i.e. many database systems, and versions of the same database system).

Comment: Yes, that was a typo (hate instead of have. I blame automatic typing). But I still disagree with you on your widespread claim. S.O uses tags to focus questions, and answers should be relevant to the tags on the question. If an Sql question uses MySql tag, you shouldn't answer with Sql Server code, for instance.

Comment: Agreed, but perhaps you missed the gist of my comment? Another question was recently closed and re-directed here. Marking this as a duplicate was imperfect (the closed question was different and addressed SQL-92 compliance beyond `SQLite` and `Access`). This question has the `sql` tag in addition to `sqlite` and is fundamentally about SQL-92 syntax. It is surely possible that addressing SQLite only *may* be too narrowly a focus. Definitely not meant as a criticism of the original answer!

Comment: Well, in that case, you probably should have comment on the closed question. duplicate votes are often less than ideal, since most questions (and most answers, for that matter) are not exact duplicates, even if the essence of the answer applies to both questions...

Answer (score 1):

`COLUMN` is not required by the SQL spec, but it is preferred. Tables could have other things you can `ADD` through proprietary extensions of the spec. The spec does not tell you what you can **NOT** do, so it's better to be explicit.

The actual [BNF grammar in the SQL-92 spec is,](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

```
<alter table statement> ::=
    ALTER TABLE <table name> <alter table action>

<alter table action> ::=
    <add column definition>
    | <alter column definition>
    | <drop column definition>
    | <add table constraint definition>
    | <drop table constraint definition>

<add column definition> ::=
    ADD [ COLUMN ] <column definition>
```

The stuff in `[ ]` is optional.

The same thing is true for other similar commands which need a `column definition`, like `ALTER COLUMN` and `DROP COLUMN`.

```sql
<alter column definition> ::=
    ALTER [ COLUMN ] <column name> <alter column action>

<drop column definition> ::=
    DROP [ COLUMN ] <column name> <drop behavior>
```

---

*copied from another answer, on a question which this was marked as a duplicate*